# Spring-Boot > Setting application.properties using JNDI

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jndi

According to this [github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/976), I can specify the location of an application.properties file. e.g.

***JNDI Environment Resource:***

```
java:comp/env/spring.config.location = /some/path/application.properties
```

What I'd like to know is:

**Can I use a JNDI binding to directly configure an individual application.properties property value in my Spring Boot application?**

I've tried the following JNDI vars (to no avail):

***JNDI Environment Resource:***

```
java:comp/env/my.env.myCustomStringField = foobar
java:comp/env/my.env.my-custom-string-field = foobar
```

[Spring Reference:](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

> If you are running in a container then JNDI properties (in `java:comp/env`) or servlet context initialization parameters can be used instead of, or as well as, environment variables or system properties.

I'm currently using [the following workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36664417/spring-boot-jndi-value-lookup/37020384#37020384).

Comment: environment variable and application properties are different. If you are using windows machine then you can set the environment `My Computer -> Right click on properties -> Advanced system settings -> Environment variables`. Here you can define **global variable** accessible by all applications. second way you can pass application parameters by using `-Dkey=value` via command line that is specific that program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what I was thinking, you can use JNDI to set the location of the `application.properties` file, and/orr override any application variables.

e.g.

```
spring.config.location = file:/some/location/properties/
my.env.myCustomStringField = foobar
```

Don't bother with the `java:comp/env/`, Spring shields you from it.